Difference between "TER / Flat fee" and "Total expense ratio (TER) p.a." of an ETF
I have been investing in the SPDR MSCI World UCITS ETF, which tracks the MSCI World index. The total expense ratio (TER) of the ETF is 0.12%.
Today, I discovered another very similar ETF called UBS ETF (IE) MSCI World UCITS ETF (USD) A-acc which appeared cheaper: its TER is 0.10%. However, when I started reading its fact sheet, I noticed that although its "TER / Flat fee" is indeed 0.10%, it also lists a "Total expense ratio (TER) p.a." of 0.29%.
What is the difference between the "TER / Flat fee" and the "Total expense ratio (TER) p.a."? And which matters to me as an investor?

The Reddit community helped with this question. In short, the TER was 0.29% until the end of 2023, but then it was reduced to 0.10%. See this post for details.
